# How Do I get uniform view size when using Image and SFSymbols in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

Here is my View:

[image: InconsistentSymbolSizes]

I want all boxes (the red rectangles) to be the same size (heights all equal to each other and widths all equal to each other). They don't need to be square.

When I create views using Image(systemname:) they have different intrinsic sizes. How do I make them the same size **without hard-coding the size.**

```
struct InconsistentSymbolSizes: View {
    let symbols = [ "camera", "comb", "diamond", "checkmark.square"]
    var body: some View {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(Array(symbols), id: \.self) { item in
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: item).font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(.white)
                    .border(.red)
                }
            }
            .border(Color.black)
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to give explicit frame width, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61984317/12299030. Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/63965325/12299030 should be helpful.

Comment: Hi Asperi!, and Thanks for the links, but I've seen them. As I mentioned, I'm looking for a way to do this without hard-coding a size.  I have a sizable array of disparate symbols and the view will be displayed on devices of all sizes, so I don't want to be forced to pick a number beforehand.

Comment: Asperi: I tried setting the width, and that didn't work. Specifying the height works, and I could use a geometry proxy and proportions of the screen, but again, I was hoping for a simpler solution. GeometryProxy messes with me sometimes. ‍♂️ If I don't get any other (better) suggestions, I'd accept your answer if you wrote one.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, maybe because this question appears again and again. The SF symbols are ... just vector font symbols, they have different geometric sizes, similarly as 'I' differs from 'M', so if you need them to have uniform size you have to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to normalize the sizes, you could use a `PreferenceKey` to measure the largest size and make sure that all of the other sizes expand to that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let symbols = [ "camera", "comb", "diamond", "checkmark.square"]
    @State private var itemSize = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Array(symbols), id: \.self) { item in
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: item).font(.largeTitle)
                }
                .padding()
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ItemSize.self,
                                           value: $0.frame(in: .local).size)
                })
                .frame(width: itemSize.width, height: itemSize.height)
                .border(.red)
            }.onPreferenceChange(ItemSize.self) {
                itemSize = $0
            }
        }
        .border(Color.black)
    }
}

struct ItemSize: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize { .zero }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        let next = nextValue()
        value = CGSize(width: max(value.width,next.width),
                       height: max(value.height,next.height))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I know I said earlier that I was reluctant to use GeometryReader, but this is EXACTLY what I was looking for! I haven't really used PreferenceKeys very much, but now I see the how useful they can be. Thanks.